# The most basic Android app on Eclipse is not building

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to make the a default android application project build and run.  This is even less than a hello world.
I am using eclipse neon 3, android 8.0, and my SDK Manager says everything is up to date.
When I create a new Android application project, it immediately has errors, which is crazy to me.

The first error is here: import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;  android.support is squiggled and unrecognized.
The error message is: "ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type".

I have spent all day on here reading about similar problems and tried the following:

-Using the SDK Manger to add "Android Support Library".
This is not shown in my SDK, even when clicking on obsolete.

-RMB Project > Android Tools > Add Support library.  This failed:
[2017-06-24 16:07:08 - Android Support Jar not found:] C:\WINDOWS\system32\v4\android-support-v4.jar
So I went and found this file somewhere and put it there.  Then it stopped failing but didn't fix my problem.

-Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Add External Jars > android-support-v4.jar.  This did nothing.

-Many suggestions have me navigating to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android where I am supposed to find all kinds of folders but all I have is m2repository.

Any help would be appreciated, but I would also like to know why this is so difficult. I have been developing in other languages for a while and have never seen a default project be so difficult to get running.
Should I be using a different IDE or something?

Comment: Eclipse has been deprecated for Android development for years now...

Comment: Eclipse has not been *deprecated*. It's only *no longer supported*.

Answer (score 0):

> Android Support Jar not found:] C:\WINDOWS\system32\v4\android-support-v4.jar

Why is your Android home directory pointed at System32?

> Found it and put it there.

That was the wrong solution to the problem. You needed to fix the environment variables for PATH and ANDROID_HOME

> have never seen a default project be so difficult to get running.

[Because the main development efforts for stability and ease of Android development are focused elsewhere](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

> Should I be using a different IDE or something?

Yes. When you downloaded the SDK, did you skip over all the Android Studio links?